# How to add multiple unity games in angular project?

Tags: angular, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I managed to to make one WebGL game working angular, but i'm having hard time adding another game.

I have both games in assets folder, and i call scripts in index.html.

```
  <!-- Unity -->
  <!-- Block Breaker -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/Games/Block Breaker v1.1/TemplateData/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/Games/Block Breaker v1.1/TemplateData/style.css">
  <script src="assets/Games/Block Breaker v1.1/TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/Games/Block Breaker v1.1/Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
  <script>
    var BlockBreakerGameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "assets/Games/Block Breaker v1.1/Build/Block Breaker v1.1.json", {onProgress: UnityProgress});
  </script>
  <!-- Laser Defender -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/Games/Laser Defender v0.2/TemplateData/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/Games/Laser Defender v0.2/TemplateData/style.css">
  <script src="assets/Games/Laser Defender v0.2/TemplateData/UnityProgress.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/Games/Laser Defender v0.2/Build/UnityLoader.js"></script>
  <script>
     var LaserDefenderGameInstance = UnityLoader.instantiate("gameContainer", "assets/Games/Laser Defender v0.2/Build/Laser Defender v0.2.json", {onProgress: UnityProgress});
  </script>
  <!-- Unity -->
```

Unity add-on on angular won't allow me to load the scripts for more than 1 game.

What work around do I have ?

Comment: only adding scripts for one game will make it work, but i want to add multiple games for multiple components.

Comment: Github [link](https://github.com/KhalidSaud/AngularUnityGames/)